# how to implement qsort in C

Tags: c, qsort

I need to implement qsort in C and sort in reverse lexicographical order. I'm confused on how to create and call the comparison function. This is what I have so far..

```
qsort (strArr, numLines, sizeof(char*) , sort);

int sort(const void * str1, const void * str2) {
 return (-1) * strcasecmp((char*) str1, (char*) str2);
};
```

Eclipse is telling me "'sort' undeclared (first use in this function)" on the qsort line, but I fear that's not my only problem. Any advice?

Thanks,
Hristo

Revision... this is what my array looks like:

```
char **strArr = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char*));
fgets(output, 256, sourceFile);
strArr[i] = malloc(((int) strlen(output) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(strArr[i],output);
```

Comment: If you want to reverse the order, don't use -1 times the comparison; just swap the `str1` and `str2` around in the call to `strcasecmp`. (On a related topic: Multiplication by -1 is a serious peeve of mine, no matter what. That's what unary negation is for.)

Comment: In other words: Best: `strcasecmp(str2, str1)`. Okay: `-strcasecmp(str1, str2)`. Lousy: `-1 * strcasecmp(str1, str2)`.

Comment: haha... thanks for the advice. I'm still a student and learning as I go along. I'll definitely keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you would need to declare sort before using it:

```
int sort(const void * str1, const void * str2);
```

then the comparison might be:

```
return strcasecmp(*(char * const *)str2, *(char * const *)str1);
```

As @Chris Jester-Young points out you can swap the args to reverse the comparison.

the pointers have to be dereferenced...

Comment: @Robert: The pointers have to be dereferenced since `qsort` calls the comparison function with pointers to the array elements, so in this case pointers to `char*`.

Comment: `qsort` calls the comparison function with pointers to two elements of the array being sorted.  The elements in this case are `char *`, so the comparison function is being called with pointers to `char *` - so `char **` is right.

Comment: doh!  caf's comment straightened me out. You (gbacon and sth) are correct. Apparently I'm up past my bedtime.

Comment: take a look at my array above. I'm not sure if I'm following you all with the dereference or not argument. Also, the sort is not sorting properly. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Hristo: Basically you should ignore my first comment. Secondly, did you update the casts in the strcasecmp call?

Comment: this is what my return is: return strcasecmp((char const*) str2, (char const *) str1);

Comment: Use return strcasecmp(\*(const char\*\*)str2, \*(const char \*\*)str1);

Comment: As to eliminate possible future confusion, I've deleted my erroneous comment which stated that the dereference was not needed. (It clearly is needed).